# How to use resolution relative css files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen-resolution

I have a website which should have different styles depending on the resolution.
[My code so far](http://jsfiddle.net/bkBZr/).
I want to check the`window.innerWidth` as my document is loading and use **small.css** when the width is smaller than **1024px**. Else I want to use **large.css**.

Any ideas?

Comment: google **css media queries**.

Comment: see also:  responsive web design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically load the required CSS document via your Javascript code.

Edit: More elaborate source code:

```
var srcURL;

if(resolution1)
     srcURL = "path/small.css";
else
     srcURL = "path/large.css";

var style = document.createElement("link")
style.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
style.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
style.setAttribute("href", srcURL)

document.getElementByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
```

Comment: yeah, that was my plan... the answer is how to do this -.-

Comment: another question: i made this - http://jsfiddle.net/2VAA3/1/ but the onLoad event doesn´t fire?!

Comment: Just because the OP asked for a JavaScript solution doesn't mean it is the appropriate choice.  It's like asking for a hammer when what you need is a screwdriver.  JavaScript is a hammer, and media queries are a screwdriver.  Sure, the hammer will work, but the screwdriver is the better choice.

Comment: @Paedow, I updated the JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2VAA3/2/

JSFiddle doesn't recognize `function foo()` way to define a method within the `JavaScript` area, although you can use it within the HTML area, within `Script` tag elements.

Answer (score 4):

Media queries.

```
/* your "big screen" CSS here */
@media all and (max-width:1024px) {
  /* your "small screen" CSS here
}
```

You can also reverse it, depending on which one you want to consider the "default" in case the browser doesn't support media queries:

```
/* your "small screen" CSS here */
@media all and (min-width:1024px) {
  /* your "big screen" CSS here
}
```

Comment: where do I do the media queries? in the <style> tags?

Comment: Here's to add to Kolink's answer.  Sites that use media queries.  http://mediaqueri.es/  You just need to add that to your css anywhere that you use styles, preferably in an external style sheet.  Anything in the brackets will be subject only when in that resolution.